# pipenv failed to lock when trying to install mysqlclient in a django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dependencies, pipenv

I tried running:

```
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

in my terminal.

However, I receive this error message:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing mysqlclient...
Resolving mysqlclient...
Adding mysqlclient to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (a01621) out of date, updating to (b35795)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠹ Locking...
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 811, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 759, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 738, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 1165, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 964, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 701, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1
```

Here is the graph:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
django-debug-toolbar==4.1.0
├── django [required: >=3.2.4, installed: 4.2.3]
│   ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
│   │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
│   └── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
└── sqlparse [required: >=0.2, installed: 0.4.4]
virtualenv==20.23.1
├── distlib [required: >=0.3.6,<1, installed: 0.3.6]
├── filelock [required: >=3.12,<4, installed: 3.12.2]
└── platformdirs [required: >=3.5.1,<4, installed: 3.8.0]
```

I tried to turn off the lock by entering

```
pipenv lock --pre --clear
rm Pipenv.lock
```

But I receive an error message that says

> rm: Pipenv.lock: No such file or directory

I am using vs Code on MacOS, python 3.10.5

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and found a solution for MacOS.
First make sure you have brew installed in your system. If not you can follow the instruction [here](https://brew.sh/)

Next, run the following command in your system.

`brew install mysql pkg-config`

After that, to install the mysqlclient in virutal environment execute the below command

`pipenv install mysqlclient`